# Can't move face in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, faces

I have just used the spin tool and I'm trying to move the face of a shape in edit mode but when I do, it doesn't move, it seems to extrude. All other faces move fine just this one. It has thicker black lines around it which the others don't but I'm not sure why.

This picture shows the face I want to move.

[image]

If I move one of the faces connected to it, it doesn't change shape.

[image]

This there any way to get it to move like all the other faces?

Comment: Most likely you extruded and then right-clicked. The face is duplicat, what happens when you delete it?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz The face disappears so you can see the inside of the tube

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified: Did you delete the face or the vertices? If it doesn't shrink the tube when you delete those, just fill the end with a new face.

Comment: I have tried deleting the face and adding a new face but the issue still remains. Same happens if I delete the vertices

Comment: Did you delete the face or the vertices? You have to delete the vertices for this to work.

Comment: I've tried deleting the vertices but the issue still remains

Comment: Would you mind uploading your  .blend?

Comment: Sure, how do I upload it?

Comment: have you tried drag and drop?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't let me add it